# Find local extrema of $f(x,y)=\sin(xy)$, such that $x\in(0,\pi), y\in(0,1)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, trigonometry, optimization, partial-derivative

Find local extrema of $f(x,y)=\sin(xy)$, such that $x\in(0,\pi), y\in(0,1)$

We want when gradient is zero.

$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x }=y\cos(xy)=0\to \cos(xy)=0\text{ [since y is non-zero]}$

$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y }=x\cos(xy)=0\to \cos(xy)=0\text{ [since x is non-zero]}$

I'm trying to find solutions to $\cos(xy)=0$, such that $x\in(0,\pi), y\in(0,1)$.

But are there any? Basically we need $xy=\pi/2$, and so if $x=\pi/2$, $y=1$ is not allowed, since $1\notin(0,1)$.

What are the solutions for this? I cannot find any.

WA gives me some strange results:
[image]

Comment: How about $(x,y)=(2\pi/3,3/4)$?

Comment: How did you find that point out?

Comment: It is easy to show that $(x_0,y_0)$, where $y_0 = \frac{\pi}{2x_0}$ for $x_0 \in ]\pi/2,\pi[$, is a local extremum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solutions are the intersection of the hyperbola $xy = \pi/2$ with the rectangular region $x\in (0,\pi), y \in (0,1)$.  These are parameterized as $(t, \pi/2t)$ for $t\in (\pi/2, \pi)$.  An example point would be $(4\pi/5, 5/8)$.